# Make my local .m2 folder as a repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is it possible to make the `.m2` folder in my local machine a repository so that other team members can use my repository instead of checking anywhere else and get the dependencies from mine? I have seen http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go but there, we have to upload all dependencies manually.

Can we make `.m2` folder (in some machine) a maven repository so others can use it?

Comment: No, you don't have to upload dependencies manually, this is exactly what maven does. You should host your own repo, like Nexus Sonatype or Artifactory, and give your team members access to your repo.

Comment: Can you describe the reason behind your decision? This is not a common scenario and there are better and easier ways to accomplish the same result with Artifactory or Nexus. like others noted.

Comment: Actually I have a machine where all the dependencies are present in `.m2` folder (all were downloaded when Jenkins build occurred) so now when other team members check in the project,instead of downloading the dependencies from outside,I want all machines to get all dependencies from this server machine first and then should try to get from outside if not found here.Got my question?

Comment: This is what a internal repository (one running on a server owned by your team) is for.  Both Nexus and Atrifactory can be setup to 'cache' external dependencies.  The bottom-line is, don't try to hack-it, set things up 'properly'.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing with you local repository is that it's stable.  If you were to put it on a shared drive, everytime one of you team builds, the artifacts that the rest of the team see will change - development being what it is, this would be a nightmare as the bugs that are introduced while developing would immediately effect the whole team rather than being isolated to one person (the assumption here is that you have multiple artifacts and build with `mvn install`).

The correct way to do this is to setup a repo, that proxies the public Maven repos.  Both [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) are setup to do this out of the box and are very easy to install on either Windows or Unix.  The proxy feature means that your repo only need contain the artifacts produced by your team and the repository will retrieve other artifacts from the public Maven repos as needed (often storing them for future use).

Comment: Actually I'm using Jenkins.So let's say person A checks in the code which requires 3 dependencies, so after Jenkins build on my server, related dependencies will be there in server's repo. Now when other people from team build the project,there won't be any need to download these new dependencies from outside again, instead dependencies from server's repo can be got and used. Got my point?

Comment: Yes, but I assume your team need to build locally before they check-in and trigger a Jenkins build.  The bottom-line is, don't try to hack-it, set things up 'properly', which means install an internal repository - they're free and can be setup in 10mins.